# scroll bars showing up when not expecting them line-height and overflow-y issue

Tags: html, css

I am getting an unexpected (to me) behaviour where a vertical scroll bar is showing up. I do not understand what the constraint on the height of the container might be.

I am able to make this problem go away by either changing the LI's margin:1 or set
the UL's lineheight: normal instead of 1.

Can anyone explain what is actually occurring? That is to say what height have I exceeded that requires a vertical scrollbar?

I created a very simple [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pGuHG/) to illustrate the issue I am having.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.content-section {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-section">
  <ul>
    <li>cheese</li>
    <li>crackers</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i am on FF and i don't see any vertical scroll bars, nvm I see it in chrome

Comment: should have specified I was debugging in Chrome.

Comment: Scroll bars no longer show up in Firefox _or_ Chrome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because your `line-height` is set to 1, which means the line-height is the same as the font-size. This causes the font to slightly overflow the line. You need to set `line-height` to a value greater than the height of the text, as you may have guessed. The text is technically behaving as it should. The height of the box is defined by the height of the lines, but the text is ever so slightly larger than the lines. Your line-height should never be equal to your font-size from a readability standpoint. I hope this helps. I know it doesn't exactly tell you where the height is coming from, but I believe you have successfully explored multiple means of combating it.

Comment: I am thinking you are right. I might be trying to be too precise. I agree that visually the line height s/b larger than the actual font.  For whatever reason our cssreset auto sets line height to 1 ( and hasn't caused other problems that I am aware of ).

Comment: I've never personally experienced what you were, but was certainly able to reproduce it in the jsFiddle. Perhaps it's time to modify your default reset. :)

Comment: I have had this issue with FF 30.0, while Chrome and IE11 had no issues. The height of a div was 25px and the line-height of the directly contained input was 25px as well, in order to vertically center the text. This caused the container to show a scroll bar. I simply reduced the line-height of the input to 23px and it works fine now. Didn't bother to really find out what the cause was though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need the overflow to set to auto, if you remove it then problem solved

If the content-section need to be a certain height, then set the height and the scroll bar will appear if it needs to be (if you need the overflow)

http://jsfiddle.net/pGuHG/2/

```
.content-section {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I have a scene when need set max-height and need scroll when cross the height, so I need to set `overflow:auto`, but when not cross the height, the scroll also show up.

I adjusted line-height to be larger and the scroll disappeared.

Comment: Hi - you could improve this question by either forking the JSfiddle, or creating a Stack Overflow embed here, that demonstrates the solution.