# Div scrollable when last element is a large text

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

When I add `overflow-x: scroll` to a div with two large texts, the div is scrollable, although it has no overflow. However, when I add another small element (br, p with smaller font size) at the end, it won't be scrollable.

Example (with TailwindCSS): Will have scroll

```html
<div class="container flex flex-col overflow-x-scroll">
  <h1 class="text-6xl font-bold mb-4">
    Lorem ipsum
  </h1>
  <p class="text-6xl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Example (with TailwindCSS): Won't have scroll

```html
<div class="container flex flex-col overflow-x-scroll">
  <h1 class="text-6xl font-bold mb-4">
    Lorem ipsum
  </h1>
  <p class="text-6xl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

This doesn't really make sense to me. The div has no visible overflow in both cases. And why would the overflow disappear when I add another element? Also the scroll is on the y axis, despite only setting overflow-x to scroll.

**Edit:** I just realized, that in Safari both examples won't scroll, however in Firefox both scroll. Originally I tried it in Chrome. It this some rare edge case or why do all three browsers behave differently?

Playground example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/S4WqS9O0BK

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the `line-height: 1` property added by the `text-6xl` class. Since any `<p>` tag you add later does not have that property the scroll is vanishing. If you were to add that property as inline css or even add that class, the later tags would show the same behavior. If you want to get rid of the scroll, all you have to do is reset line-height on the last element that has the text-6xl class. -> `line-height: normal`

Or even if you were to add some tags before that particular `<p>` tag, you see similar behaviour, but not exactly what you'd want I'm expecting.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about: https://play.tailwindcss.com/kMSrRPGbAA

This isn't the best way to get scroll though. By default, the height of the container increases to accommodate everything placed inside. So if you want scroll available on this div, you should give it a fixed height of your choosing. Once the contents inside cross that threshold you will have to scroll to see the rest

Here is an example of the proper way to scroll: https://play.tailwindcss.com/IEwEHKmnnT

Comment: I don't want scroll, I just have `overflow-x: scroll` as a default on my container class. When you say the hight increases by default, why doesn't it in this case? And you is the behavior different in Safari, Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Generally the default line-height is either set to normal which is usually larger the the size of the font. Here they've set it to 1 which means line height is the same as the font-size, since it looks better stylistically, but that is what is causing the unexpected scroll. Have a look at the accepted answer on this page, he explains it pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443642/scroll-bars-showing-up-when-not-expecting-them-line-height-and-overflow-y-issue

Answer (score 0):

The class `text-6xl` also adds `line-height: 1`. The height of the div is calculated automatically based on the text content's line heights and quantity, plus any margins and paddings. The descenders (lines going downwards in letters like p and q) are not part of that line height and therefore don't influence the automatically calculated height. But in order to allow the full text to be visible, the browser adds the scrollbar. By the way, this is independent of whether there are actually any letters in the text having descenders, so the problem persists even if you change the "p" from the dummy text.

In order to prevent the scrollbar, you can add the class `leading-normal` to the element with the class `text-6xl`: (best viewed in fullscreen, as of course you will have a scrollbar in the tiny snippet)

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container flex flex-col overflow-x-scroll">
  <h1 class="text-6xl font-bold mb-4">
    Lorem ipsum
  </h1>
  <p class="text-6xl leading-normal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

As per the comments below, the additional question arose as to why the horizontal scrollbar vanishes when removing the class `overflow-x-scroll` from the parent container altogether.

The container's `overflow` then falls back to its initial/default value, which is `visible`. You can even see the overflow of the descenders when using the dev tools to highlight the container:

[image]

Using either `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` will imply `auto` as the value for the other property, if the value is neither `visible` nor `clip`

see also MDN:

- [overflow-x > Values > visible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x#values)
- [overflow-y > Formal definition > Computed value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y#values))

Comment: But why does it change when I remove the `overflow-x-scroll`class? The overflow is on the y axis.

Comment: With `overflow-x-scroll`, you force-display the horizontal scrollbar, which is not added to the computed height of the div, but overlays the div's content and therefore you need to be able to scroll to see the full text. The initial or default value of the `overflow` property is `visible`. You can see the descenders overflow the container when you use the dev tools to highlight it. I'll ad a screenshot of that and this explanation to the answer as well.

Comment: Edited the answer to provide a screenshot and links to MDN for further reading